# OnResume and OnPause Continuly run

Tags: java, android

I have implemented code for get the image from camera and gallery.But after allow the access photos, media and files permission on device. i got the Screen overlay detected.I have turn off draw over all system app and other but comes continually. And on resume and pause loop continuously run.
this is my code please help.

**This is my permission code**

```
 if{ (!PermissionsAndroid.getInstance().checkWriteExternalStoragePermission(ServiceDetail_activity.this)) {
            PermissionsAndroid.getInstance().requestForWriteExternalStoragePermission((ServiceDetail_activity.this));
        } else {
            ImageUtils.getInstance().openImageChooser(ServiceDetail_activity.this, ServiceDetail_activity.this);
        } 

//This is my function to choose the image by camera or gallery
 public void openImageChooser(Context context, Activity activity) {
        List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri(context));
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Choose");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
        activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

**This is my onActivityResult code**

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            ImageUtils.getInstance().resampleImage(this, this, ImageUtils.getInstance().getCroppedImagePath(this));
        } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
            // Handle the error got during cropping.
        } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Cropping canceled by user.
        }
        else if (requestCode == ImageUtils.IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE &&resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            } else {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if (action == null) {
                    isCamera = false;
                } else {
                    isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
            if (isCamera) {
                selectedImagePath = ImageUtils.getInstance().getImagePath(this);
            } else {
                selectedImagePath = FileUtils.getPath(this, data.getData());
            }
            if ((selectedImagePath != null) && !(selectedImagePath.equals(""))) {

                ImageUtils.getInstance().beginCrop(this, this, selectedImagePath, false);

            }
        }

 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
      //  super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, requestCode);

    }
This my manifest code.
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have done lot off search on it.but not understand.

Please recommend me where i wrong.I have lost full day on it.

I have testing this in marshmallow device 6.0.If any buddy have some reference suggest me.find out this problem. This very important part off my project .Thanks in-advance.

Comment: share full code of your activity

Comment: this my full code

Comment: formating of post to make clear what user wants

Comment: Actually i want to get camera and gallery picture

Comment: does you override onResume and OnPause?